# How to upload data using chunked encoding?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, audio-streaming, http-chunked

I want to upload audio data through chunked transfer encoding. My application reads audio buffer after each 0.5 seconds. As soon as I get data, I want to upload this data on the server using chunked encoding. Also I want to keep the connection open. So, after 0.5 seconds, when next buffer will be available, I can upload those data on same connection.

I have tried with NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConncetion. But as soon as I start communication asynchronously, control goes to iOS and my delegates are notified. I want to upload more data using same NSURLConnection.

I have also tried with ASIHttpRequest. But I cant find a way to give data periodically and upload vi http chunking.

Please let me know if you have any standard way to upload data using transfer encoding chunked with iOS APIs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to keep the connection open?

Answer (score 0):

I would heartily recommend the [AFNetworking](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking&ei=yD57T6GiK6bY0QGcyLSaBg&usg=AFQjCNE6c3SnPVzdrmQ1-UQ5mEf8Kl9JXg) library. It seems to be the cool kid on the block for async networking on the iPhone. It was written by the developers at Gowalla and I can vouch for it's ease of use, reliability, and speed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested library. However it does not use transfer encoding = chunked.